# How to link website with Google+ to enable right pane snippet for organic search?

Tags: html, seo, google-plus, rich-snippets

There are a few websites which have nice looking Google+ snippet on the right.

Example (marked with red):

[image]

How to enable such snippet which apparently is not the same thing as "Rich Snippet" or "schema.org snippet" ?

Answer (score 0):

This is much like "related sitelinks" in that Google will only show it if it feels like it. There are multiple ways to enable this, but you can ensure that G has the data for it by following one of the four G dev guidelines here:

https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet/